# XAgent breaks previous navigation

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

If I use

**context.redirectToPrevious()**

It works great, but If I call an xagent  with or without state between opening the document and doing a close of the document. I end up navigating to the xagent.
And If I go directly to the view behind I loose opened categories in the view.

Is there a way to block an xpage to end up in the navigation/history tree?

Comment: Can you use context.getHistoryUrl(x) and set x to 2 to get to the 2nd to last page?

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches that would work.

The first is to use client-side JavaScript to open the XAgent. How you handle that will depend on whether there are values set in the browser that you are passing to `sessionScope` for the XAgent to use. If not, you can just use client-side JavaScript to open the relevant XAgent page. If you do need values, there are two options:

1. Pass them as query string parameters to the XAgent instead of storing them as `sessionScope` variables.
2. Perform a partial refresh to store the values in `sessionScope` and open the XAgent page via client-side JavaScript either in the `onComplete()` event (will trigger every time) or using `view.postScript()`, passing the relevant CSJS as a string (will only trigger if validation is successful).

The second is to set the previous page in the `beforePageLoad` event and then use that value in `context.redirectToPage()`.

Comment: Actually the xagent is used for inline lookups using front end javascript after the form is loaded. the previous page is view.xsp that olds the view. If I do redirectToPrevious or if I do redirectToPage I get 2 different results. first way gived me the view with certain categories opened. Second one gives me an initial load of the view with everything collapsed.

Comment: It's likely to need more specific refactoring of the code then, or using pagerSaveState and `viewStateBean.restoreState=true` to ensure the expand/collapse state of the categories is applied on the original page.